# Background image is not showing up in IE10 and IE11

Tags: html, css, background-image, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

I'm creating a landing page and when I test my landing page in litmus it shows up with my background image missing.

The weired thing is that my other background images are showing up in IE10 and IE11.

I added more of the code so it can be easier to help a solution.

```css
/* Part 5: Points Section */
.pad_style2 {
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 50px; }

.points_div {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  position: relative; }

.single_point_div {
  padding: 20px 0px; }

.point_circle {
  border-image: url(../images/dot.png) 30 round;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  position: absolute; }

.point_circle img {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px; }

.point_ico {
  margin-left: auto;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: #74ff00; }

.single_point_text {
  margin-left: 3px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #f32525;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; }

.single_point_text2 {
  margin-left: 55px;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: #f32525;
  line-height: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif; }

.single_point_text3 {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #69696a;
  line-height: 45px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden; }

.proto_div {
  text-align: center; }

#proto_img {
  width: 105%;
  height: auto; }

.bbsect {
  color: #d70d37;
  padding: 35px 0px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; }

/* Part 5: Client Section */
.clientsect {
  background: #052c5b url("http://transfers.calisepartners.com/TAXEASE/Visual_TEST/Lenders_Visual/Pictures/body_icons.png")  no-repeat;
  padding: 35px 0px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; }

.bottomgraphic {
        background: url(http://transfers.calisepartners.com/TAXEASE/Visual_TEST/Lenders_Visual/Pictures/Pictures/bottom_icons.jpg); 
        background-position: center top;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;

}

.bbsect {
  background: #d70d37;
  padding: 35px 0px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; }

.howitworkssect {
  background: #eaeaea;
  padding: 35px 0px;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover; }

.bold_text {
  font-weight: bold; }

.client_style1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #fff !important;
  padding-bottom: 20px; }
```

I added a link of my landing page. [Link to Page](http://transfers.calisepartners.com/TAXEASE/Visual_TEST/Delinquent_Visual/)

Comment: Capitalization issue on "Pictures"?

Comment: Does it help when you try to use background-image instead of background?

Comment: @VrataBlazek It did not work.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With just half a declaration block the problem can hardly be investigated

Comment: Probably a typo somewhere. Create a page with only the background image and see if that works in IE.

Comment: @jayms Thank you I added more information and a link to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing:

```
background: url(/*your url*/);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Instead of `background: url(/*your url*/) no-repeat;`